# Using javascript to pull URL from an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, flickr

So i've made a small script which uses the Flickr API to search for the tags on the website and it will return an image containing that tag, that all works fine.

My problem is when i try to get the URL of an image, not sure how i would do it as i've seen a few different approaches but none have really helped me, basically i want to click the save image button and it will print the URL of the current image that is on display.

I have a demo here http://jsfiddle.net/u8544ko4/

HTML:

```
                <title>get image</title>
<body>
    <form>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter Tag ... E.g. Cars">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <input type="button" id="button" value="Search For Image">
    <input type="button" id="sbutton" value="Save Image">
    </form>
    <br>
```

CSS

```
img{height:auto; float: left;}
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#button").click(function () {
                $("#images").empty();


                var search1 = document.getElementById("search").value;

                $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
                        {
                            tags: search1,
                            tagmode: "any",
                            format: "json"
                        }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.items, function (i, item) {
                        $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
                        if (i === 0)
                            return false;

                    });


                });

            });
        });
```

Thanks For reading ! Any help is appreciated !

Comment: But the URL should be the same URL as the image src, item.media.m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#button").click(function() {
    $("#images").empty();


    var search1 = document.getElementById("search").value;

    $.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?", {
      tags: search1,
      tagmode: "any",
      format: "json"
    }, function(data) {
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        $('<img/>').attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo('#images');
        $("#sbutton").prop('disabled', false);
        if (i === 0)
          return false;

      });


    });

  });

  $("#sbutton").click(function() {
    var iImage = $("#images img");
    $("#images p").empty();
    iImage.after("<p>" + iImage.attr("src") + "</p>");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  height: auto;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<title>get image</title>

<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="search" placeholder="Enter Tag ... E.g. Cars">

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <input type="button" id="button" value="Search For Image">
    <input type="button" id="sbutton" value="Save Image" disabled>
  </form>
  <br>
  <div id="images"></div>
```

Comment: Brilliant ! Exactly what i am looking for ! Care to explain how you did it exactly, i think i was way overcomplicating it for myself

Answer (score 0):

To return image src use

```
$("img").attr("src");
```

Check on your code: http://jsfiddle.net/mzvaan/axw5mteh/

Comment: Thanks ! this works aswell but i wanted to print to the page , would upvote if i could !